Why was this question asking for a clarification on a textbook proof closed?
I'm referring to this algebraic topology question. The question was asked, closed for a lack of context, and then the user (who edited the question again to indicate their frustration) eventually deleted it. Although it is deleted, users with sufficiently high reputation should be able to view it regardless. For others, I'll summarize things below.
The asker was a new user who was inquiring about a proof in Hatcher where they claimed the author was making some unjustified assumption. This does not strike me as a homework question. Rather, this seems like a student asking in good-faith after having engaged with textbook material earnestly. They provided relevant definitions, a reference to the appropriate Proposition in Hatcher, and a clear description of what they claim is the unjustified assumption. In other words, they are clearly hitting several of the "context" bullet points Willie Wong listed in the linked "canonical" answer about question context. It is not clear to me how they could have provided further context, short of knowing the answer themselves. If folks disagree, I'd love to hear suggestions on how additional context could have been added to have made this a better question.
No concrete feedback was provided in the comments. The question was just closed. This is concerning as this was a new user and I feel like they got a poor welcome from the community. They may not be back again.
I myself am a novice in algebraic topology, never really having taken the time to study it in any depth beyond the first few pages of Hatcher. I saw this question and was actually interested to know the answer. I woke up from a nap only to see that unfortunately it was removed. This was disappointing and, if I am being honest, it seems to me like another case of trigger-happy closing.

FWIW I have voted to reopen. The OP seems to be willing to improve the post once users explain the issues in the comments.

The first issue is that while the post asks for clarification of a step in the proof, the proof is not included in the main text. Right now it is included in the post as a picture. (I guess some might voted to close solely because of this - which to me is justified, since the proof is the most crucial information in the post).
Even if the proof is included as a text in the post, they still need to provide several definitions like $G(\tilde X)$. Even better, they should point out which parts of the proof do they have problem with (it took me several minutes to figure it out).
Lastly, since the question is about the specific proof in a particular book, the poster should provide context: is that particular proposition NOT already covered in the book (at least in that section) before that proof? Did they already check that?
